# Artifactory and SSO login

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, artifactory

I'm trying to setup Kerberos SSO authentication for our JFrog Artifactory.
I tried both Waffle (https://github.com/dblock/waffle) and SPNEGO solutions and failed.

1. Artifactory is installed over Windows Server 2012 R2
2. Artifactory is using it's bundled Tomcat

Does anyone have experience or encountered this issue and had managed to implement the SSO authentication?

Answer (score 0):

So, after a long period of time I had discovered that it's impossible to configure Kerberos SSO with Artifactoy on Windows server since you have to  use an httpd server module called **mod_auth_kerb.so** which is available only on Linux.

It's impossible to find it's binaries compiled for Windows server and in Linux server (Ubuntu in my case) it can be installed using **apt, apt-get** packaging tools.

If you'll be able to download the sources and compile the **mod_auth_kerb** on  Windows then it's possible to run Artifactory with Kerberos SSO on Windows Server but I strongly suggest not going on this path.